# how to fb app used on multiple pages with fb opengraph story

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm working on a facebook application that will be used across multiple facebook pages with page tab application.

The problem I'm facing is that I would like to avoid the link to application in behalf on the page.. for example, using an open graph story the output is:

{user} {action} {item} on "application name"

is there any chance to make the output like:

{user} {action} {item} on "page name"

Comment: I think one workaround could be this:

Remove the app name from the story, in your drop-down choose "No App Name" and in your item include page name with the item:

*XYZ **watched** a **ABC on DEF page***

Comment: great idea, didn't notice the ability to hide the app name!